# Meta Keys on Linux Running on a Macbook

Tags: keyboard, macintosh

Regular keyboard designs have a several meta keys. Most of them appear twice, to the left of the space key, and to it's right. `Shift`, `Ctrl`, and the `Windows/Apple` key are of this kind. The alt key appears as `Alt Gr` on the right side and is bound differently.

Notebook keyboards have a reduced set of keys. On a macbook for instance there is no control key on right side. See this [picture](https://images.duckduckgo.com/iur/?f=1&image_host=http%3A%2F%2Ffc02.deviantart.net%2Ffs71%2Ff%2F2011%2F009%2Fc%2Fe%2Fnew_apple_keyboard_by_spewboy-d36ts3o.png&u=http://orig10.deviantart.net/4210/f/2011/009/c/e/new_apple_keyboard_by_spewboy-d36ts3o.png). Additionally the `Alt Gr` key is just labeled `Alt`.

However, I'm trying to archive that all of the mentioned Meta keys are available on either sides of the space bar. The functionality of "Alt Gr" is not needed in my case. Hence:

1. For this,`Alt Gr` should be bound just to `Alt`.
2. The more difficult task would be to find a substitute for the missing right-hand `Ctrl` key. Since there is no additional key, one can think of a combination of e.g. `Alt Gr` and `Apple Key` being interpreted as `Ctrl`. Would that be possible?